# Font changing in the basic Casper theme causes icon disappearing

Tags: css, fonts, icons, ghost-blog

I'm really new to CSS and Ghost Blog Platform. I try to follow [**this instruction**](http://academy.ghost.org/basic-casper-theme-customizations/) on how to customize the font of basic Casper theme.

However, the following line in the instruction seem not to work. With this line, icons disappear, and the font of texts behind icons also doesn't change.

```
[class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before
```

By the way, I try to change my font to [Work Sans](https://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse). Here is my full code.

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,700,500,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
body,  
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,  
.main-nav a,
.subscribe-button,
.page-title,
.page-description,
.post-meta,
.read-next-story .post:before,
.pagination,
.site-footer,
[class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before {
    font-family:"Work Sans", sans-serif; /* Replace with your own font */
}
</style>
```

Any suggestion is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found out what the problem was.
In ghost academy, it is said that we can change fonts with the code below.

```
body,  
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,  
.main-nav a,
.subscribe-button,
.page-title,
.post-meta,
.read-next-story .post:before,
.pagination,
.site-footer,
[class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before {
    font-family:"Georgia", sans-serif; /* Replace with your own font */
}
```

But with that code, icons disappear as you said. To change the font without making icons disappeared, we can use codes like this.

```
<style>
body,  
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,  
.main-nav a,
.subscribe-button,
.page-title,
.post-meta,
.read-next-story .post:before,
.pagination,
.site-footer {
    font-family:"Georgia", sans-serif; /* Replace with your own font */
}
</style>

<style>
[class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before {
  font-family: "casper-icons", "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

Hope you solve the problem.